# angular 1 toaster not showing when i call on constructor

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use angular-toaster when any page is loaded.
Eg - i have two pages customer-add and customer-list, my requirement is to show toaster on customer list page when i add any new customer.

Here is my code: code in saveCustomer call back

```
this.$state.go('app.Customers', { Msg: d.Message });
```

Code in customer-list page:
     html:

```
   <toaster-container toaster-options="{'position-class': 'toast-top-right', 'close-button':true}"></toaster-container>
```

JS:

```
 static $inject=['toaster']
  constructor( private toaster: any){
     if (this.$stateParams.Msg !== null)
                this.msgToClient = this.$stateParams.Msg;
 this.toaster.pop('success', 'Success', this.msgToClient);
}
```

I am not seeing this message on customer-list page.
But i can see toaster messages in events like (click) . i tried many ways but no luck.

Comment: Do see any errors in the console (developer tools), There isn't enough information to answer that.

Comment: version of angular?

Comment: I am using angularjs 1.5.0 and  angularJs toaster Version: 1.2.0. i am not seeing any errors on console. it's just not showing.

Comment: here is the plnkr i created for this - https://plnkr.co/edit/yP57TigVM6WtIAbJK68K

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've already encounter that problem. I know it's not elegant but I solved it this way:

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    toaster.pop('success', 'Success', 'Page Load'); 
    $scope.$apply();
}, 100);
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/8P8E7NPeYa0wP2fGXleF?p=preview

Comment: This worked for me, also I found if we use $timeOut it will do the same thing.

Comment: oh yeah, it's better to use $timeout